# How to filter in multiple labels with p-listbox?

Tags: angular, filter, listbox, primeng

i want to filter on multiple labels , is there a way that optionLabel can have multiple options ?

```
<p-listbox [options]="sites" `enter code here`[(ngModel)]="selectedSite" class="ui-fluid" [listStyle]="{'max-height':'300px'}" filter="filter" optionLabel="name">

              <p-header>
                <strong>{{ 'select-site.choose' | translate}}</strong>
              </p-header>
              <ng-template let-site pTemplate="item">
                <span>{{site.value.code}} - {{site.value.name}}</span>
              </ng-template>
</p-listbox>
```

i want to filter on code and name

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting options to an array of arbitrary objects, set it to an array of select items, with a label that contains both values you want to filter on.

```
siteOptions: SelectItem[] = sites.map(s => { value: s, label: s.name + s.code });
```

Update your listbox element:

```
<p-listbox [options]="siteOptions" [(ngModel)]="selectedSite" class="ui-fluid" [listStyle]="{'max-height':'300px'}" filter="filter">
```

You are already using an item template to control how each element in the list is displayed, so no other changes may be necessary.

Comment: Your suggestion did solve the trick, even though I feel it's hacky. In my case I had to create a new attribute in the object where I just combined all the other attributes into one and used this new attribute as optionLabel. It would be nice if primeng either allows to specify multiple filterable columns or takes a function where user can filter as they wish. But thanks this helped me!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using an item template containing an `*ngIf` that called into my filtering function, and then a css rule to hide blank items from the list.

```html
 <p-listbox [options]="items" [(ngModel)]="selected"
  >
    <ng-template let-item pTemplate="item">
      <div *ngIf="isVisible(item.value)">
        {{item.value}}
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </p-listbox>
```

```js
isVisible(item) {
    if (item.fizzy) {
      return true
    }
    // any other filtering logic
}
```

```css
/* Hacky way to hide filtered items */
:host ::ng-deep .ui-listbox-item:empty {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Already prime ng have multiple attribute in p-listbox. just add in p-listbox

```
multiple=true
```

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/listbox refer the property section

Comment: Thank you for answering but i don't want multiple selection, i want to filter on multiple Labels , something like optionLabel="name || code"